# Can I bind a click event to the stage and a doubleclick to an element within it?

Tags: javascript, events, binding, konvajs

In Konva, I want to apply a click to the stage, but a doubleclick to a shape within the stage. Wondering what the best way to do this is.

Ultimately, wanted to create a floor plan where I can add tables (rectangles) to a map. If I click on the tables, Konva will allow me to add a rotation transformer. If I click outside the tables, the transformers on the stage disappear. I'm hoping that if I *double click* the tables, I can delete that shape. BUT - it doesn't appear I can both do a click on the stage, and check for a double click on an element within the stage. The code I have is the simplest example I know of to relate my ignorance about clicking and doubleclicking both on the stage and in an element on the stage.

```
//If you click on the stage, it creates the circle. And if you click on the circle, once created, I'm hoping it will be destroyed. It doesn't seem to like clicks and doubleclicks together in one area.

stage.on('click', function (e) {
    var circle = new Konva.Circle({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        fill: 'blue',
        radius: 30,
        draggable: true,
        name: "circle"
    });
    layer.add(circle);
    layer.draw();
});

circle.on('dblclick', function (e) {
    this.destroy();
});
```

Wish I could delete the circle. The circle doesn't delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stage.on('click', function (e) {
  const clickedOnEmptyArea = e.target === stage;
  if (!clickedOnEmptyArea) {
    return;
  }
  var circle = new Konva.Circle({
    x: stage.getPointerPosition().x,
    y: stage.getPointerPosition().y,
    fill: 'blue',
    radius: 30,
    draggable: true,
    name: "circle"
  });
  layer.add(circle);
  layer.draw();
});

stage.on('dblclick', function (e) {
  const clickedOnEmptyArea = e.target === stage;
  if (clickedOnEmptyArea) {
    return;
  }
  e.target.destroy();
  layer.draw();
});
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/hogahegame/edit?html,js,output